# Angular 11 - Image in assets folder not rendering

Tags: angular

I'm having issues trying to get an image to load from the assets folder.

[image]

The component where I'm trying to access the image is in app > order > order.component.html.

The path I'm using currently is...

"/assets/images/6684.png"

I have tried these also...

"./assets/images/6684.png"

"../../assets/images/6684.png"

in my angular.json file I have...

"assets": [
"src/favicon.ico",
"src/assets"
],

I have ran a prod build and I can see the images folder gets output correctly with all of the images.

I have also tried adding src/assets/images to the angular.json file but still I get a 404 on the image.

What else can I try?

Comment: try `/src/assets/....`

Comment: How is the path used in the component? Also try without the leading slash: `assets/images/6684.png`.

Comment: I have tried...

assets/images/6684.png
/src/assets/images/6684.png
src/assets/images/6684.png

none of those work.

Comment: <div>
  <img src="/src/assets/images/6684.png" alt="supplier logo" />
</div>